# How can I manipulate Math symbols in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am building a web page dedicated to explaining Math and other topics.  I'd like to animate the process of doing certain mathematical steps like adding numbers and solving an equation.  I know I can create an animated .gif but this comes with the draw back of having to find some way of drawing the symbols in a picture or maybe exporting a LaTeX rendering, etc.  I'm wondering if there is some more programmable, systematic solution.

Suppose for concreteness that I want to animate the solution to 2(x-1)=10 and then several other similar equations, and the process of dividing 123 by 45.

For some context, I have some decent but non-pro skills with HTML, CSS, JavaScript, other C-like languages, Python, and similar stuff.

Comment: Please remember, anything that is visible on page is string or image. So you have to create logic to represent partial values as string and then animate strings.

Comment: https://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: Sorry this question is too broad. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do (this is broad) is take the input of each number or symbol a person types and moves them to a specific area on a canvas with JavaScript. For example, every time a person enters in a number it will move that input into a small box or something. From there you can just use the symbols to add/subtract/multiply etc. If you wanted to make this smooth so that it goes in multiple steps you could always you the setTimeout function with JavaScript so it shows each part of the equation step by step. Also an added tip would be to check on websites that have similar functions like [Cymath](https://www.cymath.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I will choose Canvas with HTML5 and Javascript to create the animations, the good point with Canvas is that you have full control of pixels, the cons is that you will have to deal with all the stuff to create and render every single function.